# Listview populated by sql db with onListItemClick to fill textviews in other activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, textview, onclicklistener

I am filling a listview from names of a database. That is all working fine. After clicking on an Listitem with the name i would like to set the `onListItemClick`to fill out textviews in another activity. That is where i am stuck.

Here the code of my listview activity which is working:

```
public class DataListView extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

private SQLiteDatabase newDB;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotelslist);

    openAndQueryDatabase();

    displayResultList();


}
private void displayResultList() {
    ListView hotelslist = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    hotelslist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);



}

 @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  }

private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {

        DataBaseHelper newDB = new DataBaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.sqlite");

        SQLiteDatabase sdb = newDB.getReadableDatabase();


        Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM hotel ORDER BY name ASC", null);



if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
            i++;
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));


            results.add(name);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    } 

}       



    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (newDB != null) 

            newDB.close();
    }

}

}
```

Besides the name the table also contains columns "address" and "telephone". This data i would like to be filled in textviews "addressfill" and "telephonefill" of another activity with following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressfill"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/telephone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Telephone number" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/telephonefill"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to read into many tutorials out there and many posts here but didnt get around to found the right answer.

What code would i have to use for the `onListItemClick` and in my activity that uses the xml I presented. Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onListItemClick()` create an Intent and put the name in the Intent:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(DataListView.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

You must change `SecondActivity` to the class name of the Activity that will receive the name.

In this second Activity's `onCreate()`, read the String:

```java
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
if(name != null) {
    // Do something with the name, like selecting the address 
    //   and telephone number from your database to display
}
```

---

However since you are working with a database you really should use a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/). Working with a Cursor is more useful and efficient.

---

> how can i do it for the other columns data of the table like address and telephone?

You have two options:

1. In your second Activity use a query like:

   ```
   "SELECT address, telephone FROM Hotel WHERE name = '" + name + "'"
   ```

   But if multiple hotels have the same name, you will get more than one address...
2. Change your query in your first Activity to:

   ```
   "SELECT name, address, telephone FROM Hotel ORDER BY name"
   ```

   Now in `onListItemClick()` you can pass the name, address, and telephone number all at once, but you will need to store the address and telephone number somewhere... This is where a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) is *extremely* useful.

Comment: thank you. that works for the name. how can i do it for the other columns data of the table like address and telephone?

Comment: thank you. i went with your first option and saved all the strings in another array i created. that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up listeners on list items, you will need to extend array adapter and put the listener code in the adapter:

```
public class SettingsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
          // put your listener in here
                  mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do work here
                }

     }


}
```

In other words, the simplelistadapter is not sufficient to do want you want, you will need to create your own.

**edit**

Here's a good example of creating your own custom ArrayAdapter: [Custom Array Adapter Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjAlNfa6obU)

Comment: thanks for you answer but i cant quite follow. I have a list and when clicking on one list item i would like to move to another activity that displays the name, address and telephone in the textviews that i created. i would not want to put an extra button.

Comment: cant i pass the strings somehow to my new activity and then put them into the textviews?

Comment: The button is just an example - you can put the listener on ANY view.  When the event fires, open the new activity with an intent.  My design style often attaches the listener to the entire layout, so a tap on any part of the list item will fire the event.

Comment: thanks for you help but that seemed a bit too complicated for me the adjustments would have been too big. i went with the other option that Sam gave me. thx